# no se porque no me imprime una lista (js)

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un código para separar los elementos de una cadena en un array y que dicho array se represente en un span en forma de lista. el código es el siguiente:

por algun motivo de que desconozco no llega a entrar en el ciclo for.

```
<span id="lista"></span>
<script>
var texto="hola,adios";
var separado=texto.split(",");
   for (var i = 0 ; i < separado.lenght ; i++) {
      var imprimir="<li>"+separado[i]+"</li>"; 
      document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML=imprimir;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Le estás errando en el `id` del span: `document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML=imprimir;

Comment: @DamiánAlva no es solo eso, Tu fallo es sencillo, has escrito lenght cuado ha de ser **length**

Comment: Y está declarando la variable *imprimir* en cada iteración del bucle, machacando el valor con un **=** en vez de concatenando con un **+=**

Comment: si, el id lo habia cambiado para evitar datos del proyecto, Nicolas gracias me estaba volviendo loco

Answer (score 0):

intenta cambiar esto por separado.lenght por separado.length

```js
var texto="hola,adios";
var separado=texto.split(",");
var imprimir = '';
for (var i = 0 ; i < separado.length ; i++) {
  imprimir=imprimir  + "<li>"+separado[i]+"</li>";
}
document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML=imprimir;
```

```html
<span id="lista"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un typo, has puesto en el for `separado.lenght` en lugar de `separado.length`.

De todas formas, si quieres iterar sobre los elementos de un array, puedes probar a usar el método .forEach del prototipo array, tu código quedaría así.

```js
const text = "hola,este,es,mi,texto"

text.split(',').forEach(value => {
  const currentList = document.querySelector('#lista').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('#lista').innerHTML = `${currentList} <li>${value}</li>`
});
```

```html
<span id="lista"></span>
```